# SQL (Netezza) Query Performance

Tags: sql, performance, netezza

I have a table that has 26 columns and over 10^8 rows and contains some stock market data. I am performing a pretty basic query but it isn't as performant as I'd expect:

```
select * from tableA where (cusip_id, mkt_close_dt) in (
               select cusip_id, max(mkt_close_dt) from tableA
               where mkt_close_dt >= '2012-12-25' and mkt_close_dt <= '2013-01-01'
               and cusip_id in ('025081753', '04314H709', '115291833', 
               '086233103', '119530202', '22544R305', '256206103', 
               '256219106', '471023887', '476313101', '471023598', 
               '66537V336', '592905103', '665162400', '779547108', 
               '741481105', '77956H864', '693391682', '779557107', 
               '77957P105', '693390700', '77956H104', '780905709', 
               '784924789', '880208400', '885215566', '779919109', 
               '00141A545', '09256H328', '31429A105', '471023762', 
               '04315J860', '543495840', '592905848', '592905509', 
               '693390130', '921937793', '78464A516', '73935S105', 
               '464287465', '464288281', '464288612', '464288869', 
               '464287630', '464287648', '464287481', '78464A417', 
               '464288588', '464288273', '464287457', '464287176', 
               '922908553', '922908512', '922908744', '922908736', 
               '922042858', '464287226', '921937835', '902641679', 
               '06738C778', '78464A854', '78464A847', '33734K109', 
               '33735B108', '33734Y109', '464288596', '464287507', 
               '464287804', '464287150', '464287200', '464287622', 
               '464287655', '464287499', '464287689', '464287846', 
               '464287127', '464288208', '464288505', '78464A649', 
               '72201R304', '78467Y107', '921910873', '464287135', 
               '464287101', '73935X450', '73935X443', '73935X435', 
               '78355W106', '78463X863', '808524607', '808524102', 
               '808524201', '78464A813', '78462F103', '72201R205', 
               '78464A664', '464287432', '78464A805', '922908751', 
               '921908844', '922908629', '922908413', '922908769', 
               '922908637', '922908652', '18383M498', '78464A490', 
               '78355W205', '921937827', '464288422', '81369Y407', 
               '73935X195', '81369Y605', '81369Y100', '81369Y308', 
               '81369Y506', '81369Y886', '81369Y209', '81369Y704', 
               '81369Y803', '92206C664') group by cusip_id
```

Note that I will be creating the list of `cusip_id` dynamically (i.e., it will be constantly changing) and the `mkt_close_dt` will also vary. Finally, I don't want to use a temp table either. Given these constraint, how can I possibly improve performance?

Comment: I don't know about optimizer plans in Netezza, but check if the optimizer pushes the `cusip_id` list to the outer query (or try Gordon's approach)

Comment: How many rows does this return , how long is it taking to run now, and what runtime would satisfy you?

Comment: Also please provide the DDL fir the table, specifying at least the distribution column and any organize clause, as well as your version.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to get the records from the maximum date for a given `cusip_id` given those conditions.

I would recommend window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select a.*,
             max(mkt_close_dt) over (partition by cusip_id) as maxdt
      from tableA a
      where mkt_close_dt >= '2012-12-25' and mkt_close_dt <= '2013-01-01' and
            cusip_id in ('025081753', '04314H709', '115291833', 
               '086233103', '119530202', '22544R305', '256206103', 
               '256219106', '471023887', '476313101', '471023598', 
               '66537V336', '592905103', '665162400', '779547108', 
               '741481105', '77956H864', '693391682', '779557107', 
               '77957P105', '693390700', '77956H104', '780905709', 
               '784924789', '880208400', '885215566', '779919109', 
               '00141A545', '09256H328', '31429A105', '471023762', 
               '04315J860', '543495840', '592905848', '592905509', 
               '693390130', '921937793', '78464A516', '73935S105', 
               '464287465', '464288281', '464288612', '464288869', 
               '464287630', '464287648', '464287481', '78464A417', 
               '464288588', '464288273', '464287457', '464287176', 
               '922908553', '922908512', '922908744', '922908736', 
               '922042858', '464287226', '921937835', '902641679', 
               '06738C778', '78464A854', '78464A847', '33734K109', 
               '33735B108', '33734Y109', '464288596', '464287507', 
               '464287804', '464287150', '464287200', '464287622', 
               '464287655', '464287499', '464287689', '464287846', 
               '464287127', '464288208', '464288505', '78464A649', 
               '72201R304', '78467Y107', '921910873', '464287135', 
               '464287101', '73935X450', '73935X443', '73935X435', 
               '78355W106', '78463X863', '808524607', '808524102', 
               '808524201', '78464A813', '78462F103', '72201R205', 
               '78464A664', '464287432', '78464A805', '922908751', 
               '921908844', '922908629', '922908413', '922908769', 
               '922908637', '922908652', '18383M498', '78464A490', 
               '78355W205', '921937827', '464288422', '81369Y407', 
               '73935X195', '81369Y605', '81369Y100', '81369Y308', 
               '81369Y506', '81369Y886', '81369Y209', '81369Y704', 
               '81369Y803', '92206C664')
     ) t
where mkt_close_dt = maxdt;
```

Comment: Should the alias for `a.*` be defined somewhere?

Comment: @slaw . . . Yes, that is true.